# Why it is said that stroke aesthetic works on shape 21-24 only?

Tags: r

If `stroke` is the size of the borders of 25 built-in shapes in R, logically it should work on every shape (we can exclude filled shapes 15 to 20).

```
ggplot ()+ geom_point(mapping=aes(x=1:5, y=1:5), shape=12, size=7)
```

[image: This is a graph without stroke]

```r
ggplot ()+ geom_point(mapping=aes(x=1:5, y=1:5), shape=12, stroke=2, size=6)
```

[image: This is a graph with stroke]

So it seems to me that stroke works on shapes 0-14 too. Can anyone explain this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ggplot(data.frame(a = 0:25, stroke = rep(0:2, each = 26)),
       aes(x = a, y = as.character(stroke), shape = a, stroke = stroke)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, color = "red", fill = "blue") +
  scale_shape_identity()
```

Stroke impacts every shape, but the effect is much more obvious on 0-14 and 21-25. **21-25 are the shapes where stroke will be most useful** in balancing the relative visual prominence of the outline color (defined by "color") and the interior (defined by "fill").

We can observe three groups of shape behaviors:

- 0-14 are created by lines whose thickness is controlled by stroke (becoming invisible when stroke is 0) and whose color is controlled by "color." The strokes have round corners.
- 15-20 have both an interior and an outline that is impacted by stroke (though less and differently than the others; note that triangle 17 retains sharp corners with larger stroke width, while 2 and 24 do not). Both the interior and line color are controlled by "color."
- 21-15 have both an interior and an outline that is impacted by stroke. "Color" defines the stroke color and "fill" defines the interior color. The strokes have round corners.

[image]